# How to build external HTTPS webhook for Google Action builder

Tags: https, actions-on-google, google-assistant, actionbuilder

I want to build a simple conversation with a scene calling an external webhook :

https://ipaddress/Serveur_Cron.php?cmd=ActionOnGoogle

In action Builder, "Scene" tells me to link with a webhook name :
[Action Builder Scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGTJH.png)

but in the webhook tab I can give the https url, but not any name ?
What did I miss ?

How do i manage to call an external API from Actions Builder ???

Answer (score 0):

First of all, **you are right on your way**. Just confused.

Now, It is asking you to name your webhook for the current scenario so that later you can take action according to that scenario.

A webhook can be called multiple times in different scenes.

It helps us to handle at backend like.
Let's say you have used webhook at three scenes named respectively

example1,
example2,
example3

Following code can be useful at your webhook

```
app.handle('example1'); // For 'A' actions
app.handle('example2'); // For 'B' actions
app.handle('example3'); // For 'C' actions
```

That is why it is asking to name it.

you can call external API(s) inside your webhook.